# Kivy Screen Transition with time delay

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

The aim to to have a button on my home screen, when pressed a delay screen will open. A time delay of 5 seconds is then needed after which the screen will return to home.

My problem is any time delay linked to the button press, stops the delay screen from opening

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import time


Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: 1, .8, .3, 1
        text:'Home'
        size_hint: .8,.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'y':.1}
        on_press:root.manager.current = "delay"

<TimeDelay>:
    name: "delay"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            text: "delay"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'top':0.5}
            on_press:root.manager.current = "main"
""")
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TimeDelay(Screen):
        time.sleep(5)
        sm.switch_to('main')

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(TimeDelay(name='delay'))

class timedelayapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    timedelayapp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use time.sleep() if you don't want to block UI. Use [kivy.clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) instead.

It is not clear to me if you want to go back to screen 5 seconds after a button press, or 5 seconds after entering the screen. This example will come back after button press:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    TimeDelay:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: 1, .8, .3, 1
        text:'Home'
        size_hint: .8,.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'y':.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = "delay"

<TimeDelay>:
    name: "delay"
    FloatLayout:
        ButtonDelay:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            text: "delay"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'top':0.5}
            ##on_press: root.manager.current = "main"
            on_press: self.clocked_switch()
"""


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TimeDelay(Screen):
    pass


class ButtonDelay(Button):
    def clocked_switch(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.switch_to_main, 5)

    def switch_to_main(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.current = "main"


class TimeDelayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeDelayApp().run()
```

If you want to go back 5 seconds after entering screen, use similar clocked function call, but from [Screen.on_enter()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen).